# Is Allah ever a common noun, or is it always a proper noun? And if so, do they look different?

Tags: arabic

Is Allah ever a common noun?

or is it always a proper noun?

And if so, do they look different in the arabic?

Comment: What are (your definitions of) a common and a proper noun?

Comment: Of course it is -- a proper name to be precise.

Comment: In Shona, *chipo* is both a proper name and a common noun. In Kuria, *chaacha* is a name conventionally assigned to a class of people (first born males) so is arguably not a "proper name". So this is not an "of course".

Comment: @user6726 Believe it or not, I'm talking about English!

Comment: I see, I didn't understand that since the question was not about English, so I naturally thought you were commenting on the question asked.

Comment: OP, if you can edit this question to include some of the information from your comments, it might make it better. As is, the question you are asking is trivial & answered by a dictionary: الله‎ /aɫˈɫaːh/ is a proper noun meaning "the monotheistic God" (*not* just in Islam, the word is also used to refer to the singular God of the Christians, Baha'i, Jews, etc.). The common-noun version is الْإِلٰه‎, /al-ʔi.laːh/ which means "(the) god" in reference to any deity. If this answer is not satisfactory, then you need to do a better job explaining what it is you are seeking.

Comment: ...in particular, the word "Allah" is known to have predated Islam; Muhammad's father's name was "Abdullah", Arabic translations of the New Testament and Christian jewelry have been found which use the term "Allah", and there is evidence that the chief deity of the pagan pre-Muslim Arabs was often called "Allah".

Answer (score 3):

The word *Allāh* is a contraction of *al-* "the" and *ilāh* "god". However, the contraction is only used as a proper name for the Abrahamic G-d; "the god" in any other context is uncontracted *al-'ilāh*.

So no, it's always a proper noun when it's contracted.

Comment: So colloquial "yallah" includes a proper noun?  (And note, the question did not ask about Arabic only.)

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer True, but the question is tagged #arabic and nothing else. It seemed fair to restrict the answer to Arabic.

Comment: You say Allah  " only used as a proper name for the Abrahamic G-d" <--- That sounds like a big claim. So before islam, did pagans, those not Jewish or Christian, ever use the term Allah for any of their Gods? Did the term or name Allah originate with Jews and Christians, or did the term/name originate with Islam?

Comment: @barlop The word literally means "the deity"; compare the Hebrew _elohim_ from the same root. Christians generally used _kyrios_ (Greek) > _dominus_ (Latin), calquing Hebrew _adonai_. I'm afraid I don't know much about pre-Qur'anic Arabic, but if you asked that as a separate question someone else might be able to help.

Comment: @Draconis Elohim means God or gods , it can include false gods or gods that shouldn't be worshipped. It's more like Ilah than Allah. And I guess perhaps I should edit my answer to be clear. I'm not asking about just Quran onwards. I'm talking of arabic prior to the influence of islam too.  You can't really answer the question avoiding pre quranic arabic. It's not an islammic question so i'm not asking specifically about quranic arabic.  Or just modern understanding of arabic as heavily influenced by islam which is very narrow

Comment: @barlop. In ancient North and South Arabian inscriptions we have the god Allāh and also the goddess Allāt. These are not exclusive to the “Abrahamic” “monotheistic” religions.

Comment: @fdb  Indeed, and this is why this answer is incorrect, as i'm asking about arabic not about islam and not about arabic with islammic belief mixed in.   I wonder if in those ancient times, Allah was "the most supreme god"?  Or perhaps "the God" in the sense that the one that stands out.If it's a name it suggests they thought there was only one and then it seems like it wasn't meant as a title.

Comment: @barlop I'm not sure you can find any modern Arabic without Islamic influence. If you're curious about the history of Arabic ("has the Arabic contraction *Allāh* ever been used as a common noun in the past?") you should ask that as a separate question, possibly on Arabic.SE.

Comment: @fdb   If it's a name then maybe it suggests they thought there was only one and then if it was meant as a title too, then it'd perhaps have been thought to only apply to that one pagan allah moon god, husband of allat?

Comment: @Draconis what Arabic SE are you talking about? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283101/arabic-stack-exchange   says there's nothing

Comment: @barlop Ah, I'd thought there was one? In that case, it would be worth asking here; questions about language history are more on-topic than questions about language usage, so asking specifically about the contraction *Allāh* and its origin could be on-topic.

Comment: I'm not experienced on this site, can you post an example of the question that owuld be accepted here and link it to me on www.pastebin.com ? then I can look at ti see if it is what I want, and post it.  Or perhaps you could post the question? Thanks  I have no idea how to ask the question without somebody saying i'm asking about language usage

Comment: @barlop Sure, I can try to post a question in a couple hours.

Comment: @Draconis thanks